# How to set NODE_PATH=. for node.js app hosted in openshift

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, openshift

I use custom node.js cartridge on openshift 
[icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs](https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs) .

How can i set NODE_PATH=. for app start in package.json ? Should i provide it in package.json like that :    `"start": "NODE_PATH=. NODE_ENV=production node app.js"` ,
either i should use something like here 
[Dindaleon/hapi-react-starter-kit](https://github.com/Dindaleon/hapi-react-starter-kit/blob/master/package.json)    - some npm package like `cross-env`

I have line in main app.js file. There is folder named 'config', in the same directory with app.js, in folder config placed file index.js, file index.js have code with  'module.exports = Object.assign({ ...some conifg object... });' . When i delete NODE_PATH=.  , node throws "Error: Cannot find module 'config' " .

```
var config = require('config');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of [openshift-cartridge-nodejs](https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs) :-)

Having `"start": "node app.js"` in your `package.json` should be just enough.

If you take a look at [`bin/install`](https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs/blob/master/bin/install), you'll see that `NODE_ENV` is already set to `production` by default in the cartridge setup script.

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by setting `NODE_PATH` to `.`. There's a single Node.js version installed.

If you're generally interested in how you can set custom environment variables in an OpenShift-deployed application, have a look at the docs [here](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html). Basically you'll have to use the `rhc` command-line utility like this:

```
$ rhc env set <Variable>=<Value> <Variable2>=<Value2> -a App_Name
```

Comment: I have line in main app.js file. There is folder named 'config', in the same directory with app.js, in folder config placed file index.js, file index.js have code with  'module.exports = Object.assign({ ...some conifg object... });' . When i delete NODE_PATH=.  , node throws "Error: Cannot find module 'config' " .